# Web Accessibility: Redundant link- Adjacent links go to the same URL for pagination

Tags: accessibility

I have a number of paginated items and when the next numbered page and the `next` button are the same, then the wave accesibility tool raises an alert about redundant links that point to the same URL. Can this be resolved or should I ignore it? An example of my pagination code is below.

See `page 2` and `next` where the links are similar below for the issue in question.

```
<nav class="pagination" aria-label="Pagination">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/1/"
         aria-label="Page 1"
         aria-current="page">
        1
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/2/" aria-label="Page 2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3/" aria-label="Page 3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/4/" aria-label="Page 4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/5/" aria-label="Page 5">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2/">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is that accessibility tool really calling it an _Alert_? Usually there are Errors and Warnings, the latter meaning that after some manual verification they can be ignored. In this case, it should be the latter, as you can ignore it. You should add `aria-current="page"` to the current page, though, consider removing the aria-labels as they are redundant with the navigation title and might fail [Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html), and change the navigation’s name, as _Pagination_ is tech jargon. _Page navigation_ might be better.

Comment: Which accessibility tool is it, and could you provide some link to the check result?

Comment: @andy it is the wave accessibility tool by webaim. It labels alerts in yellow.

Comment: @andy It looks `aria-current` is already being used in the code example.  And having "page 3" instead of just "3" as the link name might be helpful so the `aria-label` is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be ignored. As @andy says in his comment, this is more of a warning than a failure.  In general, it's best to not have adjacent links go to the same destination but it's not a [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) failure.

In your code example, the links are not **adjacent**.  They're not "next" to each other in the DOM. There are several links in between the "2" link and the "Next" link so I'm not sure why it would be flagged as an issue anyway.

If I copy/paste your code into a demo and run [WAVE](https://wave.webaim.org/extension/), it does **not** flag the "Next" link as redundant.  But if I change the "Next" link to point to the same destination as the "5" link, then I **do** get the redundant warning since the links are indeed adjacent to each other.

One might argue that the "2" link and the "Next" link fail [WCAG 3.2.4 Consistent Identification](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#consistent-identification) since you have two links that go to the same destination but they're not labeled the same, but in your case, it makes sense that they have different names so I wouldn't fail 3.2.4 if I were doing an accessibility review.